# OpenFrameworks Doesn't Compile with c++11, GPGS needs c++11

Tags: android, eclipse, c++11, google-play-games, openframeworks

I'm working on a game that is built using [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/setup/android-eclipse/).

In it's make files, there is a -nostdlib CFLAG.

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Game Services' [c++ sdk](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid)

I've copied the GPGS include & libs folder into my "libs project", and added the .a file to OF's PROJECT_STATIC_LIBRARY and the include folder to OF's header search paths.

Now, when I compile the project without adding -std=c++11 to the CFLAGS, I see 2 major errors in gpg.h:
'chrono' in namespace 'std' does not name a type and
'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

But when I add -std=c++11 to CFLAGS, I see 3 major errors in OF code, all stemming from the use of 'dynamic_cast_tag". I've added a picture of ofTypes.h, (from open frameworks), where the error is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While the latest commits to the openFrameworks project compile it with c++11, the Google Games cpp sdk will not link due to duplicate md5_block_data_order symbols.

I've implemented a workaround.

I am no longer using the Google cpp sdk. Instead I am implementing the integration with Google Game Services in OFActivity.java and using jni from a cpp wrapper that I've written.